# RecursionError when trying to access correct column values using if/then statement

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like this after I split and expanded it using `.str.split(' ', 40, expand=True)` to a whole physical address for each row.

```
0       1   2             3        4        5           flag
1255    N   Camino        AVE      1071     San Diego   1     
1255    N   DelSur        AVE      1191     San Diego   1     
3642    E   CONSTITUTION  DR    San Diego   CA          0
```

Now, I want to write a conditional function which overwrites column[4]. I want to say if flag==1 then replace column[4] values with whitespace else keep the value from column[4]. This is example the output should look like this:

```
0       1   2             3        4        5           flag
1255    N   Camino        AVE               San Diego   1     
1255    N   DelSur        AVE               San Diego   1     
3642    E   CONSTITUTION  DR    San Diego   CA          0
```

However, in my case, it spits out an error. Here is my code:
 `df[4] = ['' if i=='1' else addresses[4] for i in df['flag']]`

```
**The output is an error: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object**
```

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We usually do `np.where`

```
df[4] = np.where(df['flag']==1, '', df[4])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
df.loc[df.flag == 1, '4'] = ''
```